# Wouldn't it be easier to import all packages, put them in .sty file and don't think about them any more?

Tags: packages, import

Latex is very old and I believe that only importing the needed packages was important back then. Nowadays, does it make sense to do dozens of tiny imports? Why not just import all and then don't worry about it anymore? I suppose there might be some compatibility issues between packages but can't this be solved by overriding with the newest package? This way we only have to import a package very occasionally. All the packages could be put in a .sty file...

Comment: Since when is tikz small? Since when are all packages compatible? How do you load 100s of fonts at the same time? A lot of people prefer to not load stuff they don't use.

Comment: you're much too overoptimistic if you think all packages are compatible.  from production experience working for a math publisher, i can tell you that many hours are lost trying to create workable books and journals from authors who have used incompatible packages even though they were informed which ones were not usable in the required context.

Comment: Still, is there no way to import a lot of packages that are compatible between them all at once?

Comment: Related: [Creating a default preamble](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/278818)

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from doing it for yourself based on all the packages you require, but there's no one-size-fits-all for all LaTeX users. Why would, say, a theologian or a linguist want the overhead of loading `amsmath`, `siunitx`, `listings` and various other science packages? Or why would a mathematician want to load `reled­par` etc?

Comment: I get the impression that a lot of people copy preambles from templates without ever wondering what all those packages are doing.  OTOH,  beamer, memoir and KOMA seem to have a "everything than isn't forbidden should be compulsory" attitude.